# How to run an arbitrary command in bash -c?

Tags: bash, shell

I basically want to do `bash -c "$@"`, but that doesn't work (my command does not get run). While `eval "$@"` works fine, what's the difference?

I want to do something like this:

myscript:

```
function run_it() {
  bash -c "$@"
}

run_it $@


./myscript MY_VAR=5 make my-target
```

Comment: "doesn't work?" is not a suitable description of what's happening, read [ask].

Comment: How do you start your script?

Comment: @Cyrus Not sure what that means

Comment: Short of using `eval`, you can't do what you want. The assignment is special `bash` syntax, not a command itself. What is the purpose of `myscript` instead of just running `MY_VAR=5 make my-target`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the quoting. This should work better:

```
function run_it() {
  bash -c "$*"  # Change 1
}

run_it "$@"     # Change 2
```

The reason for change 1: `$@` is special when used inside quotes, like `"$@"`. Rather than expanding to a single argument, it expands to a series of quoted arguments: `"MY_VAR=5" "make" "my-target"`. As a result, the `-c` flag only receives the `MY_VAR=5` part, which is executed with `make` and `my-target` as arguments `$0` and `$1` respectively. By using `"$*"` you *do* end up with a single string. Note that this still doesn't handle spaces correctly; not sure how to fix that.

The reason for change 2: Here we *do* want every argument to be quoted individually. This makes sure that arguments aren't being split too soon. It might be pointless until you fix the other spaces issue first though.

Comment: This won't necessarily work correctly. `run_it foo "a b c" "d e f"` becomes `bash -c "foo a b c d e f"`.

Comment: @chepner I clearly mentioned that (twice), but I don't know how to fix it easily. Feel free to edit if you have a better idea.

Comment: If you don't know how to fix it, perhaps not answering the question would have been prudent.

Comment: Handling spaces is not always needed.

Comment: Yes, spaces *always* need to be handled correctly. The function doesn't know what arguments it might be called with.

Comment: Depends on the use case. For me, the $* worked perfectly. If Thomas didn't answer, I would be in a world of hurt. Can you not be so stuck up?

Answer (score 0):

We could use eval in a subshell.

```
function run_it() {
  (eval "$@")
}

run_it "$@"
```